# How to print Japanese characters using PDFBox2.0?

Tags: pdfbox, cjk

I want to print some Japanese characters in my PDF using PDFBox2.0.I already know I can load a ttf file to display the Japanese characters.Like this:

```
InputStream fontGStream = new FileInputStream("C:\test\IPAexfont00401\ipaexg.ttf");
PDFont fontGothic = PDType0Font.load(doc, fontGStream, true);
```

But I want to create a new font to support Japanese instant of using the ttf file.I have tried it's useful in PDFBox1.8,but in PDFBox2.0 the code doesn't work again.Can anyone give some advice.

```
        COSDictionary systeminfo = new COSDictionary();
        systeminfo.setString(COSName.REGISTRY, "Adobe");
        systeminfo.setString(COSName.ORDERING, "Japan1");
        systeminfo.setInt(COSName.SUPPLEMENT, 6);

        
        PDFontDescriptorDictionary fd = new PDFontDescriptorDictionary();
        fd.setFontName("ＭＳゴシック");
        fd.setFlags(4);
        fd.setFontBoundingBox(new PDRectangle(new BoundingBox(-500, -300, 1200, 1400)));
        fd.setItalicAngle(0);
        fd.setAscent(1400);
        fd.setDescent(-300);
        fd.setCapHeight(700);
        fd.setStemV(100);

        
        COSDictionary cid = new COSDictionary();
        cid.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.FONT);
        cid.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.CID_FONT_TYPE0);
        cid.setItem(COSName.BASE_FONT, COSName.getPDFName("KozGoPr6N-Medium"));
        cid.setItem(COSName.CIDSYSTEMINFO, systeminfo);
        cid.setItem(COSName.FONT_DESC, fd);


        COSDictionary font = new COSDictionary();
        font.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.FONT);
        font.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.TYPE0);
        font.setItem(COSName.BASE_FONT, COSName.getPDFName("KozGoPr6N-Medium"));

        font.setItem(COSName.ENCODING, COSName.getPDFName("UniJIS-UCS2-H"));
        COSArray array = new COSArray();
        array.add(cid);
        font.setItem(COSName.DESCENDANT_FONTS, array);


        PDFont pdFont = new PDType0Font(font);

        String str = "日本語出力テスト123";
        stream.setFont(pdFont, 40);
        stream.beginText();
        stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 100);
        stream.drawString(new String(str.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-10646-UCS-2")),"ISO8859-1"));
        stream.endText();
        stream.close();
```

In PDFBOX2.0,when I run the code,it outputs the below error.

```
    Apr 13, 2021 9:59:01 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType0 <init>
WARNING: Using fallback BIZ-UDGothic-Bold for CID-keyed font KozGoPr6N-Medium
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType0.encode(PDCIDFontType0.java:401)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.encode(PDType0Font.java:443)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:333)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDAbstractContentStream.showTextInternal(PDAbstractContentStream.java:300)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDAbstractContentStream.showText(PDAbstractContentStream.java:254)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:37)
    at PDFBoxTest30.main(PDFBoxTest30.java:89)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question -  you know that `PDType0Font.load()` is the way to do it, why would you want to do it differently?

Comment: Because my client doesn't want to using the external ttf file.If using the ttf file,when it's upgraded,we also need to deal with the upgrade.
If we use the PDFBox to show the Japanese,we only need to deal with the PDFBox upgrade.

Comment: You could put the font into the resource directory (be careful to turn off filtering). `PDType0Font.load()` works with input streams too.

Comment: Or are you trying to create a PDF without embedded fonts? PDFBox doesn't like that at all, and the users of such PDF files will have trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply.Is there a way to show Japanese without embedded fonts?

Comment: You could create the file with embedded fonts (without subsetting), then remove /FontFile (or /FontFile2 or 3, not sure which one, have a look with PDFDebugger), and save. Then see whether it works. Users who don't have the font may not be able to display the PDF. Some viewers may fail.

Comment: `Because my client doesn't want to using the external ttf file.If using the ttf file,when it's upgraded,we also need to deal with the upgrade` I disagree, because an external ttf file (from the PDF recipient system) is used when displaying the PDF, so you're adding a risk. When you use a font file in the resources, then you keep a fixed behaviour which is more safe.

Comment: I can't agree with you any more.But my client and me are also very curious about if there is a way to create a font like PDFBox1.8 to display Japanese.If you can give any advice it's very thankful.

Comment: You should use the strategy that I mentioned a day ago "You could create...". You seem to have a good understanding of the COS model so I think you can do it. But I don't want to make an answer from that because it's a bad practice that I don't want to promote.